# Auto indent and brace alignment in Geany?

Tags: autocomplete, tabs, indentation, auto-indent, geany

I usually write Java code so that my braces are aligned. Currently when I type a '{' in Geany it autocompletes with a '}'. However, is there a way so when I press enter the ending brace goes two lines down (aligned with the original) and my cursor is on the line between the braces shifting by a tab?

For example, currently this is what happens:

```
{}
```

Goes to:

```
{
       }
```

Instead of what I want:

```
{

}
```

Comment: Which version Geany are you using? I cannot reproduce this.

Comment: frian sorry about necroing but I have the same situation now, I'm using Geany version 1.29 (at least according to the package manager).

Answer (score 1):

In your snippets.conf file `Tools > Configuration Files > snippets.conf`, create a section named 'Special'if it does not exist and add an entry `block={\n\t\n}`. I think that would do the trick. This is how your file would look

```
...
[Special]
...
block={\n\t\n}
...
```

Comment: added the same but still changes are not reflecting after restart as well..